# Log date on cell text change in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to log the date in a cell when a user tries to enter a text in another cell. To give you a clearer picture, I would like today's date to be logged in cell B1 when a user writes something in A1. I used this formula in B1:

```
=IF(A1="","",B1=TODAY())
```

but it doesn't work! Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: google sheets or excel?

Comment: If you're trying to do this in Google Sheets it's not possible to set a static timestamp without using Google Apps Script, since `=TODAY()` will recalculate with the rest of your sheet.

Comment: ^ And if you're doing it in Excel, you'll need VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste this in **B1** cell:

```
=IF(A1=""; ; TODAY())
```

[image: 0]

---

**note:** the date will change daily

### _______________________________________________________

otherwise, it would be:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) {                       // SHEET NAME
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) {                            // COLUMN OF ENTRY
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);                      // OFFSET +1 COLUMN
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy");                             // TIMEZONE + DATE FORMAT
  nextCell.setValue(newDate);
}}}
```